# web site access control PHP

Tags: php, security, web-config

I want to protect my large class.php files on my site.
My site runs on IIS (godaddy);
I use `web.config` files;

Question:

If the page the users are viewing `require('class.php')`, Can this `class.php` file  be restricted to only the server scripting? Or does the file need to be in a folder that is accessible. I would also do the same for my `db.php` file containing the database password.

**EDIT**

If i make a page on my desktop with a link to my index.php file and that i right click it and save it i now have the php file. i can open it ans see that it requires clss.php. The i can repeat this and get the class.php file. This is what i want to prevent

**END OF EDIT**

So basically the php processor would have access to the file but not the users that  would try to download them.

If this is possible what would be the rule to add in my web.config file?

Thank you!

Comment: from being accesed by anything else then the php processor. i dont want users to be able to download them. but i require them to render the page.

Comment: The only way an actual php file should be sent in response to a request is if there are errors in the server configuration or something similar. If you are concerned, you can always try to curl the URL of the php file or load it in a browser, and verify that it is executed and not returned.

Comment: Best practice is to keep them outside of the folder that is publicly accessible. Then, if the PHP engine fails for whatever reason (perhaps a temporary misconfiguration), the raw files cannot be output. Another option for your web.config is to use the denyUrlSequences section. Lots of examples on the net for that.

Comment: php is compiled server side - so th users can never download the php

Comment: I wish that were true, Dagon, but there are certainly a lot of "my browser is trying to download the php files instead of showing my website" questions haha

Comment: require(__DIR__ . '/../db.php'); was what i was looking for Thank you rjdown

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to [define a constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) in the first file, then in your class.php you can exit if it's not defined. Just put that as your first line, and you will ensure that its not called from another entry point.

Or, just place your class.php outside of the web root.